# How can I stress test my Raspberry Pi

Tags: performance, benchmarking, battery

I recently picked up a battery powered USB cell phone charger and I'm running some tests to see what kind of battery life I will get.  Right now I'm just testing at Idle. I want to also run a test using as many resources as possible. It seems easy enough to use prime95, or run a program with a busy while loop to test the CPU, but Is there something I can run to max out the GPU as well?  Are there any other recommended programs that I can use to run the Pi at full capacity?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Whbn the foundation announced the enhanced [overclocking support](http://www.raspberrypi.org/archives/2008) they mentioned running quake 3 was a good test of the improved performance. This forum post has the [installation details](http://www.raspberrypi.org/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?f=78&t=18853).

Answer (score 30):

You can perform a Raspberry PI stresstest with the sysbench tool.

First example calculate primes

```
sysbench --test=cpu --cpu-max-prime=20000 run
```

Second example test the I/O Output of your Raspberry Pi

```
sysbench --test=fileio --file-total-size=2G prepare
sysbench --test=fileio --file-total-size=2G --file-test-mode=rndrw --init-rng=on --max-time=300 --max-requests=0 run
sysbench --test=fileio --file-total-size=2G cleanup
```

Third example memory read and write

```
sysbench --test=memory run --memory-total-size=2G
sysbench --test=memory run --memory-total-size=2G --memory-oper=read
```

Comment: here is one example of how to use sysbench for a temperature test: https://youtu.be/1AYGnw6MwFM?t=501

Comment: Buster had an older version of sysbench for me (0.4.12) so I had to change `--cpu-max-prime=20000` to `--max-requests=20000`

Answer (score 17):

I wrote the little command-line tool [stressberry](https://github.com/nschloe/stressberry) the other day which stresses your Raspberry, measures the core temperature, and produces nice plots. Install with

```
pip install stressberry --user
```

and run with

```
stressberry-run out.dat
stressberry-plot out.dat -o out.png
```

[image]

Answer (score 10):

For the CPU and most other things you can use

```
nice -19 stress-ng -c 4 --metrics --timeout 60s
```

For the GPU they suggest [GeeXLab](http://www.geeks3d.com/20160215/raspberry-pi-opengl-2-1-support-tested-with-geexlab-0-9-6-0/) at [geeks3d.com](http://www.geeks3d.com/20160322/tested-raspberry-pi-3-vs-raspberry-pi-2-cpu-and-gpu-benchmarks-burn-in-test/).

Answer (score 4):

XBMC doing multimedia decoding might be a good test as well as the UI there is in OpenGL. A game that constantly hammers the frame buffer (memory!) while including a numerical simulation like OpenTTD is also a pretty good test. The generic Dhrystone and Whetstone benchmarks might also be good. There's an OpenGL game I'm working on porting called Armagetron Advanced (which isn't really ready yet, sadly) that uses both the GPU and CPU quite heavily. That'd probably be perfect once it's done.

On a side note, if you're worried about the Pi cutting out on battery power, it might be worth investigating the [MoPi](https://www.kickstarter.com/projects/hamishcunningham/mopi-mobile-and-24-7-power-for-the-raspberry-pi?token=a93b16b7) board. It monitors voltage and a daemon running in the background will trigger a clean shut down when it's out of power.

Answer (score 2):

Either of these two:
`for i in 1 2 3 4 ; do nice -n 20 openssl speed >/dev/null 2>&1 & done`
or
`for i in 1 2 3 4 ; do nice -n 20 cat /dev/zero > /dev/null & done`
will suffice, though the former will exercise RAM more. 
Use a media player to decode a matroska .mkv file concurrently, and you’ll have a nice fat peak load. `nice` will keep your Pi responsive enough to let you do a `for pid in $( jobs -p ) ; do kill -9 $pid ; done`, flushing the bowl like a big boy. Set it as a function:
`killalljobs()  { for pid in $( jobs -p ) ; do kill -9 $pid ; done ; }`